# RC transmitter/receiver for underwater robot

Tags: underwater

I am working on a project to build a remotely controlled underwater robot. The max depth the robot has to dive is 40cm. I tested the 2.4GHz RC transmitter and receiver and it could work only up to 15cm below water surface, even though not very stable. I googled a lot, but didn't find any proper transmitter and receiver set with minimum 4 channels, in frequency range of less than 100MHz or at 433MHz. Would anyone please suggest where I can find one or how I can assemble one with off-the-shelf modules?

Comment: why do you need multiple channels?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* roTor-roTor, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: In general it is better ask *How do I solve this problem?* than *What do I need to buy to solve my problem in this way?* as you may preclude answers providing better solutions. In this case, given the existing answer which suggests what you want to do is not possible, you may want to ask a new question (linking to this one) which asks how you can communicate with your [auv](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/tags/auv/info).

Comment: @MarkBooth Ok. I will rephrase my question to meet the criteria. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thanks for your [new question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/19578/37) and I hope that you manage to find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Is the robot going to have an over-the-water antenna?

If not, then electro-magnetic communication is a no-chance under-water, if the water is salty (seas, oceans) or if the distances are long. The underwater communication is usually done with sound (acoustic waves) - which can travel huge distances, thanks to the higher density of water, compared to air.

[**Here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwater_acoustic_communication) you can find some more information.

---

More to-the-point information [**here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect):

> At **1 megahertz** the skin effect depth in wet soil is about 5.0 m, **in seawater it's about 0.25 m**.

It means that in sea water the EM waves will travel no more than 25cm, at 1MHz. The higher the frequency, the shallower the depth.

---

More formulas [**here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penetration_depth).

---

Why EM is not the way: [Radio-controlled_submarine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-controlled_submarine), unless you have an aerial antenna for the submarine.

---

**If** the water is fresh (no dissolved salts) and **if** the distances are (relatively) short, then **the project might have a chance**, depending on the specific details.